# How to remove few objects from a List of Object

Tags: jakarta-ee, collections, iterator

Suppose I have a list of Employee Object and each Employee Class has got properties like employeeName, employeeAddress, salary etc. Now i have to remove the Employee objects whose name is "John" and Salary > 40000.

List empList = new ArrayList<>();
// Add milions of Employees to empList.

According to my understanding to remove employee with above condition, i should use the below code:

```
Iterator<Employee> iterator = list.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      Employee employee = iterator.next();
      if ("John".equals(employee.getName) && employee.getSalary>40000) { 
      iterator .remove(); 
    }
 }
```

So basically the above code will remove the required Employee object from the list.
Please let me know if my understanding is correct.

Apart from that please clarify the following:
1. When we have millions of records then how we will address this issue.
2. Difference between iterator.remove() and list.remove()

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) if you wanna keep objects alive you can only filter needed objects

```
list.stream()
.filter(emp->"John".equals(emp.getName()) && emp.getSlaray() >40000)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

2) if you're iterating over a collection and use:

```
Collection.remove()
```

raises specifically ConcurrentModifcationException cause of changing the state of the object used previously to construct the explicit series of calls necessary to complete the loop, bu when you use

```
Iterator.remove()
```

you change underlying collection AND re-evaluate the explicit series of calls necessary to complete the loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.

Answer (score 0):

It it isn't good to have millions of objects loaded at once. How do you get all those records? If you read them from database it is better to make the filtering there with SQL.

```
where e.name = "John" and e.salary > 40000
```

If you read them from a file you should not read them all at once, that is for database too. You can fetch records to batches of lets say 1000.

If you implement it like above you can also use streams:

```
List<Employee> filteredList = list.stream()
    .filter(employee -> employee.getName().equals("John"))
    .filter(employee.getSlaray() > 40000)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and then you can have your filtered lists of 1000 rows and treat them separated.

Comment: 1. What is the advantage of using streams as compared to Iterator. 2. Can we make use of parallel streams.

Comment: 1) There is no advantage, it is what fits your needs. I prefer Streams for the readability perspective but if you have so many records as you said you should consider the time penalty which may come up with Streams over for loops.
2) Of course you can.